# Vue - How to pass and use dynamically multiple components as props

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I'm using AgGrid as the grid to show the data in the site.

Following this example [Example: Rendering using VueJS Components](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#example-rendering-using-vuejs-components), I'm able to use different components to be rendered into different columns.

Now that I need to implement this grid in multiple views, I want to make a "custom component" that implements the ag-grid-vue component, and receives just the column definitions, row data and components (if the columns are rendering another component).

Something like this:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <ag-grid-vue
      :animateRows="true"
      :columnDefs="columnDefs"
      :frameworkComponents="frameworkComponents"
      :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
      :gridOptions="gridOptions"
      :pagination="true"
      :paginationPageSize="paginationPageSize"
      :rowData="rowData"
      :suppressPaginationPanel="true"
      colResizeDefault="shift"
      ref="agGridTable"
      rowSelection="multiple"
    ></ag-grid-vue>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue";

export default {
  name: "AgGrid",
  components: { AgGridVue },
  props: ['columnDefs', 'components', 'rowData'],
  data() {
    return {
      gridApi: null,
      gridOptions: {},
      defaultColDef: {
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        suppressMenu: true
      },
      frameworkComponents: null
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.frameworkComponents = this.components;
  }
}
</script>
```

Now the parent will pass all the data needed:

```js
<ag-grid :column-defs="columnDefs" :components="frameworkComponents" :row-data="gridList"></ag-grid>
```

The problem comes when I try to pass these components as props:

```js
this.frameworkComponents = {
  squareRenderer: SquareRenderer,
  cubeRenderer: CubeRenderer,
  paramsRenderer: ParamsRenderer,
  currencyRenderer: CurrencyRenderer,
  childMessageRenderer: ChildMessageRenderer,
};
```

Obviously, my custom component doesn't know these components because they are not imported, so the view could not find those components. Since each view will display diferent columns, and these one could or not display renderer components, I need to pass all the components needed to the grid component and import them.

Any ideas how to import and use those components?